# Vite/Microbundle node module with import statement

Tags: typescript, next.js, create-react-app, vite, craco

I am developing a node module that will be consumed by applications that use Webpack and Next.js. The node module uses `microbundle` when building and publishing the module.

The module imports a 3rd party library and uses a different URL based on the environment. I'm just learning about how each processes imports at runtime and not entirely sure how this works. Ideally, I would like the application consuming our module to pass a host for the 3rd party library. However, using any conditionals or passing any variables as the host causes the following error: `Error: Cannot find module https://example.com/library`.

Using `tsc` to build my module all of the solutions below work, but `microbundle` does something with dynamic imports causing the error.

### This works

```js
const importLibrary = async (env: 'dev' | 'prod'): Promise<LibraryType> => {
  const devHost = 'https://example-dev.com'
  const prodHost = 'https://example-prod.com'

  if (env === 'dev') {
    return await import(`${devHost}/library`)
  }

  return await import(`${prodHost}/library`)
}
```

### Causes an error

```js
// Using a conditional in host
const importLibrary = async (env: 'dev' | 'prod'): Promise<LibraryType> => {
  const host = env === 'dev' 
     ? 'https://example-dev.com'
     : 'https://example-prod.com'

  return await import(`${host}/library`)
}
```

```js
// Passing prop from application
type HostType = 'https://example-dev.com' | 'https://example-prod.com'
const importLibrary = async (host: HostType): Promise<LibraryType> => {
  return await import(`${host}/library`)
}
```

All options work in a vite application, but Next.js and Webpack(using [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/) or [CRACO](https://craco.js.org/) to build) fail with the error I have above. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**NOTE**: I am simplifying my code, the actual code I am using does have a try statement. I do `console.log` the error and return undefined if it can't be imported.